# Не работает QLineEdit отказывается работать вместе с валидатором и входной маской

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qregularexpression

Создаю *QLineEdit* и задаю ему входную маску **8(999)999-99-99**, а так же применяю к нему *QRegularExpressionValidator* с регулярным выражением *8\(\d{3}\)\d{3}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}*. Выглядит это так:

```
QRegularExpression telNumExp("8\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d{3}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{2}");
this->telNumberEdit->setInputMask("8(999)999-99-99");
this->telNumberEdit->setValidator(new QRegularExpressionValidator(telNumExp, this));
```

По итогу в *QLineEdit* появляется маска, но туда ничего не вводится. По отдельности это все работает, а вместе - нет. И да, оставить только маску, ведь она по факту и так ограничивает любой другой ввод, нельзя - это пример работы для учебного конспекта по теме *"Регулярные выражения"*. Как можно решить данную проблему?
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Вначале установите валидатор, а потом маску и все заработает (то есть, просто поменяйте строки кода местами)

Comment: Спасибо, все завелось